# Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in a multiple aggregations elasticsearch

Tags: json, search, elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to build a query allowing me to make multiple aggregations (on the same level, not sub aggregations) on a single query. Here's the request I'm sending :

```
{
    "index": "index20",
    "type": "arret",
    "body": {
        "size": 0,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "anim fore",
                            "analyzer": "query_analyzer",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "fields": [
                                "doc_id"
                            ],
                            "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "anim_fore": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "suggest_keywords.autocomplete",
                    "order": {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    "include": {
                        "pattern": "anim.*fore.*"
                    }
                }
            },
            "fore": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "suggest_keywords.autocomplete",
                    "order": {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    "include": {
                        "pattern": "fore.*"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error when executing this query :

```
Error: [parsing_exception] Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [fore]., with { line=1 & col=1351 }
```

I've been trying to change this query in many forms to make it works but I always end up with this error. It seems really strange to me as this query seems compatible with the format specified there : [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations).

Maybe there is something specific about terms aggregations but I haven't been able to sort it out.

Comment: It seems that it has something to do with the include clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your `include` settings, which should simply be strings

```
    "aggs": {
        "anim_fore": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "suggest_keywords.autocomplete",
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                },
                "include": "anim.*fore.*"              <--- here
            }
        },
        "fore": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "suggest_keywords.autocomplete",
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                },
                "include": "fore.*"                    <--- and here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I realised it just a second ago. Do you have any idea why the include.pattern syntax work when there's only one aggregation but doesn't when there's multiple aggs ?

Comment: Weird, I've never seen the `include.pattern` anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You have trailing commas after `doc_id` and after closing array tag for `must`, your query should look like this

```
"must": [
    {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "anim fore",
            "analyzer": "query_analyzer",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
                "doc_id" // You have trailing comma here
            ],
            "operator": "and"
        }
    }
] // And here
```

Comment: Well I just modified the json in my post in order to shorten. These trailing commas don't exist in the original json.

Comment: There should not be pattern property for include, it just should be string